# Regular Expression to ignore all text between 2 points in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, regex

> Start code is "abc123" now, this is irrelevant text and characters,
>   possibly new lines and line breaks, quotes etc. Finish.

I would like my regular expression to find a match where there is text that begins with 'Start code is', retrieves the value that follows within the quotes (in this case abc123), but then ignores all that immediately follows that closing quote UP UNTIL the word 'Finish'.

So if I had the following text:

> This is some dummy text. Start code is "abc123" now, this is
>   irrelevant text and     characters, possibly new lines and line
>   breaks, quotes etc. Finish. And this is some more dummy text.

... the match would be successful, and I would be able to retrieve the value abc123. That is the only part that I actually need to use.

Comment: What do you want as an output? For `This is some dummy text. Start code is "abc123" now, this is irrelevant text and characters, possibly new lines and line breaks, quotes etc. Finish. And this is some more dummy text.` string You want it this? `This is some dummy text. Start code is . And this is some more dummy text.`

Comment: If you only need `abc123` (from your example), why do you care about what's next to `Finish` ?

Comment: In the actual full scenario, there would be multiple instances of text beginning with 'Start code is' and ending with 'Finish1', 'Finish2' and so on. I want to be able to look for a particular instance of one of these text blocks (lets say, find the one that has 'Finish2' at the end for example) and so what I want as the output is the 'abc123' (from my example, though this value will be different within each instance) for the associated/matched text block.

Comment: You need to show us the regular expression you're using, and the C# code you're using (which method on `Regex` are you calling?). The behavior you're asking for is *what you get by default* -- regular expressions normally don't care what comes before or after the match string -- so you're probably specifically doing something to *disable* that default behavior, and we'll be better able to help if we can see what you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(str, ".*Start code.[^\"]*\"([^\"]*)\"[^\"]*.*Finish\\..*");
if (matches.Count > 0)
{
    result = matches[0].Groups[1];
}
```

Basically, you just need to check the results of Regex.Matches. The only "trick" used here, is the fact that I'm limiting myself for looking for non-quote characters, both before, between and after the quotes.

Comment: So would this not work then if the content that appears between the Start code and the Finish part, contain quotes? Is there any way to match regardless of what characters appear between my start and finish points?

Comment: What kind of text do you want to get in such a case? For example: `Start code is "abc123" now," Finish.` What is the output? abc123? now?

Comment: The output should only be the abc123 (or whatever the value is that is located in that position within the matched instance of that Start/Finish block of text).

Comment: Do you mean the first instance? Because in the example I gave you both "abc123" and " now" are between quotes, and between Start/Finish

Comment: I've edited my answer to return the first string that is both between quotes, and Start/Finish.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern with lookarounds:

```
@"(?<=Start code is "")[^""]+(?="")"
```

or a simple capturing group:

```
@"Start code is ""([^""]+)"""
```